# Why does the python {:016X} .format() specifier not allow sizes greater than 2**52 in Brython?

Tags: python, string, format, brython

I should be able to turn a value up to (`2**64`)-1 into a zero-padded, 16-hex-nibble string... So why does the below error out when I get up to a size beyond `2**52`?

```
>>> a = "{:016X}".format(2**52)
>>> a = "{:016X}".format(2**53)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <string>, line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Could this have to do with limitations in Brython, which is converting things to javascript? (Because I get that error in the Brython REPL [here](https://brython.info/tests/console.html?lang=en), but not in a local normal Python3 REPL)

Comment: The biggest value that you can use that doesn't cause an error is `(2**53)-2`.  No doubt this is caused by the conversion to JS, and Brython not doing the right thing with a JS BigInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the developers confirmed it was a bug:
https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/1624